# Maven repository that sometimes works

Tags: maven, github

I hosted a java project on github.
The project is located [here](https://github.com/bvandenbon/brugo).

The project is really just a java library, and I wanted to create a maven repository for it. Because this is tricky, I followed [a guide](https://gist.github.com/fernandezpablo85/03cf8b0cd2e7d8527063) which explained me which project structure to follow. He applies a trick: create a 2nd branch named "repository". As you can see the jar files are in there.

[image: Github Maven setup]

That all went well, I made my first build, and then I created a java "Hello World" project to test if I could use this new maven dependency. So, I created a pom file with a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>brugo</groupId>
        <artifactId>brugo</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And to tell maven where to find this dependency, I added this one:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>brugo</id>
        <url>https://github.com/brugo/brugo/raw/repository/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The good thing: sometimes it works.
The bad thing: sometimes it does not work.

And I am trying to find out what could be wrong. This is what IntelliJ looks like when things go wrong:
[image: in IntelliJ]

And I've seen this error message showing up:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx: 
Could not find artifact brugo:brugo:jar:0.1.0 in
brugo (https://github.com/brugo/brugo/raw/repository/) -> [Help 1]
```

I tried an `mvn clean install -U` several times, but without success.

I had the same problem on a different computer yesterday, then suddenly I got it to work without really knowing how.

Comment: Why do you need a maven repository on Github for the project?

Comment: You can just ask a repository on maven central for your github project. The process https://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html  explain this. And as you can use org.github.yourname as groupname, validation can be fast.

Comment: @bvdb It's much easier to go via Central in particular for consumers of your library...

Comment: BTW: You project setup is simply wrong. you are not following the conventions over configuration paradigm. `src/main/java` production code. `src/test/java` unit tests...

Comment: @wargre, I never really payed much attention to the groupid. But since I own the domain "brugo.be" I decided to use "be.brugo" in this registration. But if I understand you correctly, that may take a little longer for them to validate ?

Comment: @khmarbaise indeed, I am not using the default path that maven proposes. But I'm just overruling that by defining a `<build><sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>...</build>` setting. But I don't think it's relevant. My class files are in the jar, so that seems to be in order.

Comment: @wargre thanks, worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @wargre for pointing me in this direction.
It's indeed easier (and more convenient) to set it up to be directly in the central maven repository.

**http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html** explains all the required steps. **Here follows a summary.**

**First release:**

1. Create a JIRA account and a project
2. Add plugins to the `pom.xml` file
3. Add more meta to the `pom.xml`
4. Download/install GPG and create keys
5. Create a `settings.xml` which contains your credentials.
6. Run `mvn clean deploy`
7. Verify the result in the staging repository
8. Release when happy, drop and retry while unsatisfied.
9. Post a comments on the JIRA ticket
10. Admire the result in the maven central repository.

**Consecutive releases:**

1. Update the version number in `pom.xml`
2. Run `mvn clean deploy`
3. Release (manual/automatic)